# How can I use an "outside" class on rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, include, require

So, I have this ruby file and I want to use it in my rails project, but I don't have a clue on where or how to start, I've read about include and require, some sites tell me to use require, some to use include, and even to use both, but that's it. I would like to know where to put the necessary code, how to use the file's methods and where to put the file in the project directory, because I want to call it from a view but I don't know if that is the best, I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but rails is still new for me. I appreciate all the help you can offer. Thanks for your time.

The file I'm trying to use is the one that converts numbers to words created by Faustino Vasquez limon and it's a full class:

**numeros.rb**

```
class Numlet

  def initialize(numero)

    @numero = numero.to_s.reverse.split("")
    @i = 0
    @j = 0
    @parte1 = []
    @parte2 = []
    @especial = ""
    @numlet = []
    @bandera=0
    @bandera1=0
    @a =[["Uno","Dos","Tres","Cuatro","Cinco","Seis","Siete","Ocho","Nueve"],
      ["Diez","Veinte","Treinta","Cuarenta","Cincuenta","Sesenta","Setenta","Ochenta","Noventa"],       
      ["Ciento","Doscientos","Trescientos","Cuatrocientos","Quinientos","Seiscientos","Setecientos","Ochocientos","Novecientos"]]

  end


  def especial 

    @numlet[@j]  = case @especial
    when "11"then  "Once"
    when "12"then  "Doce"
    when "13"then  "Trece"
    when "14"then  "Catorce"
    when "15"then  "Quice"
    when "16"then  "Dieciseis"
    when "17"then  "Diecisiete"
    when "18"then  "Dieciocho"
    when "19"then  "Diecinueve"
    when "21"then  "Veintiun"
    when "22"then  "Veintidos"
    when "23"then  "Veintitres"
    when "24"then  "Veinticuatro"
    when "25"then  "Veinticinco"
    when "26"then  "Veintiseis"
    when "27"then  "Veintisite"
    when "28"then  "Veintiocho"
    when "29"then  "Veintinueve"
    else return 0
    end
  end

  def repetir

    case @numero.length
    when 0..3 then @parte1[0] = @numero[0..@numero.length]
    when 4..6 then @parte1[0] = @numero[0..2];@parte1[1] = @numero[3..@numero.length]
    when 7..9 then @parte1[0] = @numero[0..2];@parte1[1] = @numero[3..5]; @parte1[2] = @numero[6..@numero.length]
    else return 0
    end
  end

  def convierte

    @bandera1=0
    @i=0
    case @bandera
    when 1 then @numlet[@j]="mil";@j+=1
    when 2 then (@parte2.length==1 and @parte2[0]==1) ? @numlet[@j]="millon" : @numlet[@j]="millones";@j+=1
    end
    @especial = [@parte2[@i+1],@parte2[@i]].to_s
    if especial != 0
      @i+=2
      @j+=1
    else
      if @parte2[@i].to_s =="1"
        @numlet[@j]="Un"
        @i+=1
        @j+=1
      end
    end
    while @i < @parte2.length
      if @parte2[@i].to_i ==0
        @i+=1
        @bandera1+=1
      else
        if @parte2.length != 1 and @bandera1 ==0
          if @i == 1
            @numlet[@j]="y"
            @j+=1
          end
        end
        @numlet[@j] = @a[@i][@parte2[@i].to_i-1]
        if  @i == 2  and @bandera1==2 and @numlet[@j]=="Ciento"
          @numlet[@j]="Cien"
        end
        @j+=1
        @i+=1    
      end
    end
    @bandera+=1
  end

  def termina

    @numlet.reverse.join(" ")
  end

  def a_letra

    if  repetir != 0
      @parte1.each do |@parte2|
        convierte
      end
        print "#{termina}\n"
    else
      print "Este numero no puede ser convertido\n"
    end

   end

end
```

That is what i want to use from my app. Thank you for your time.

Comment: It really depends what your ruby file is doing...if its just a couple of helper methods then you could just include it in the app/helpers directory and include it. If its an entire library then it would go under lib/ and you'd need to have some sort of initializer. Post a snippet of the code and we'd be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's your own class and you want to use it in one of the Rails views, there's many ways of using that code.

My own way and you may or may not choose to do it this way would be to include that file in the `lib` directory and then `require` it in the helper file of the you view you want to include it in.

This would allow you to access methods and initializers from that file and you would be able to create methods in your helpers to use on your views.

Comment: Thank you Leo! It worked! I actually tried first to put the require on the controller and the model and it works too! Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: No problem, don't forget to up vote and select as answer when you can :)